# Suppose $f\in C^2[\mathbb{R}^2] $ , it holds $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) \gt0 $

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f\in C^2[\mathbb{R}^2] $ , and for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, it holds
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) \gt0 $$
Prove there is no extremum (i.e. local maximum ) for $f$.

---

I suppose we could done this like give an arbitrary point, we can always find another point in a circle around it to have lower or greater value. But the space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, I failed in convert the condition $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) \gt0 $ into something useful.

Comment: if $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$, then it has a global minimum at $(0,0).$ Perhaps, you miscopied the question?

Comment: @ dezdichado Forgive me. I'm a terrible English user. I took 'extremum' to mean the 'local maximum'.

Comment: If you know how to do it in an open domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you are basically done. Suppose $f$ attains a local maximum at $p$. Then, you can find a circle centered at $p$ in which $f(p)$ is the maximum. But you have claimed to proven that is impossible, no?